# Developer story tags are pretending to be clickable

Tags: feature-request, design, developer-story

So I was browsing my developer story and wanted to click the tags I had gathered there.
To my surprise they are non-functional, but do display a hover effect, as if they are clickable.

My suggestion is: Either make them clickable to the relevant tag results, or remove the hover effect.

[image]

Comment: Though they show hover effect, cursor is still selection cursor. Personally, I think the hover effect is necessary to make them feel like [tag:tag] the same way they look on all other sites. Making them clickable could be better solution.